# Laravel 5.6 ytake/laravel-couchbase authentication issue

Tags: php, couchbase, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6 and using couchbase SDK to establish the database connection. When I run the test on core PHP I am able to access the bucket but using ytake/laravel-couchbase package it's throwing an error of authentication.
My code looks like below:

```
public function index()
{
    $authenticator = new \Couchbase\PasswordAuthenticator();
    $authenticator->username('test')->password('test123');
    print_r($authenticator);
    \DB::connection('couchbase')->table('`test-lab`')->get();
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to authenticate using mentioned package or if it automatically does that so what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
// Auth init
$authenticator = new \Couchbase\PasswordAuthenticator();
$authenticator->username("test")->password("test123");

// cluster init
$cluster = new \Couchbase\Cluster("cluster-name");
$cluster->authenticate($authenticator);

// bucket init
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket("test-lab");

// get data
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test-lab';
$query_result = \CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString($query);
$result = $db->query($query_result);

// return results as an associative array
return $result->rows;
```